# Is there a way to reduce the execution time of o function in python?

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx

I want to compute the sum of all the edges' weights of my network graph in python. Actually, I have more than 88000 edges so it makes more than 3 hours to finish. Is there any solution to reduce the execution time?
Here is the function to compute the weight of each given edge:

```
def weight_edge(i,j,g):
  neighborhood_i=neighborhood(g,i)
  neighborhood_j=neighborhood(g,j)
  neighborhood_commun=len(intersection(neighborhood_i,neighborhood_j))
  neighborhood_total=len(neighborhood_i)+len(neighborhood_j)
  if(neighborhood_total-2!=0):
     return(round(neighborhood_commun/(neighborhood_total-2),3))
  else:
     return 0
```

Where i and j are two connected nodes and g is the graph.

Comment: If you don't have memory constraints, save the neighborhoods of all nodes first so that you don't recalculate both neighborhoods for every single edge.

Comment: I think that the problem is in exploring all the neighbours.

Comment: Have you considered doing this by means of a list of adjacency lists ? Also, accessing the upper diagonal values from the adj matrix might be very efficient. The issue in these scenarios would be build such data structures in the first place. Furthermore, depending on how often you use such information later on, it could be worth to pay a high price at the beggining to build one of such data structures.